# Unable to restore mysql database via Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: mysql, database, jenkins, jenkins-groovy, restore

I am unable to run a restore from jenkins pipeline. I have the below command running. :

```
sh('mysql -u wp-user -h xx.xx.xx.xx -pXXXYYZZ -e prod-$dbName < /mnt/restore1/prod-$dbName.sql')
```

Receive the below error and the job ends. Seems like Jenkins just doesn't read anything after the '<' symbol in the above code.

```
+ mysql -u wp-user -h xx.xx.xx.xx -pXXYYZZ -e prod-db1
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'prod-db1' at line 1
```

Comment: did you find any ways to restore db in jenkins ?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue which I posted here https://serverfault.com/questions/1106556/restoring-mysql-in-jenkins-job-error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-serv